# Custom Container for hosting OpenLDAP in Bluemix

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud, openldap

I am trying to create custom container for hosting OpenLDAP in Bluemix.
I am following the steps mentioned in the link:
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/images/add-your-own/

At Step 6, where I need to tag the docker image, I receive the below error:

```
D:\>docker tag openldap registry.ng.bluemix.net/devopstest/openldap:aa9f496f321

FATA[0001] Error response from daemon: DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"  
"<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>"
<h1> Method Not Allowed <h1>
<p> The method is not allowed for the requested URL. <p>
```

Any help or pointers is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: could you update your question with the output of the `env | grep DOCKER` command?

Answer (score 0):

`registry.ng.bluemix.net/devopstest/openldap:aa9f496f321` should math the pattern:

`registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image_name>:<tag>`

In the [Bluemix documentation](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_images_adding_ov.html), we find:

> **Namespace:** A unique name to identify your private repository within the Bluemix registry. The namespace is assigned one time for an organization and cannot be changed after it is created.
>
> #### To identify the namespace for your organization:
>
> - From the Bluemix user interface:
>
>   **Note:** You can only identify the namespace from the Bluemix user interface if an image was added already to the private repository for the organization. You cannot find the namespace by clicking one of the IBM-provided images. Use the command line option instead.
>
>   1. From the Bluemix Catalog, click an image. The container creation window opens.
>   2. Under the image name, click Copy image URL. The namespace can be retrieved from the copied URL, which is in the following format: `registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image_name>:<tag>`
> - From the command line:
>
>   - Cloud Foundry plug-in:
>
>     `cf ic namespace get`
>   - ICE:
>
>     `ice namespace get`
>
>   Combine your namespace with the Bluemix registry domain and the image name to get the private Bluemix repository URL for an image: `registry.ng.bluemix.net/<namespace>/<image_name>:<tag>`

Is `devopstest` matching your private Bluemix repository name?